# Android Studio: How to link my .aar library to multiple projects?

Tags: android-studio, android-library, aar

I have a library that I use in multiple projects. Every time I update (and rebuild) this library, I do not want to have to copy and paste the .aar to EVERY single project that uses this library. What is the most convenient, efficient way to accomplish this?

Note: I'm running Android Studio 1.0 RC2 on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1):

Upload your android library as an artifact to [maven central](http://search.maven.org/) or [jcenter](https://bintray.com/).
Checkout [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) guide that i totally find worth mentioning here to understand how to upload your android library to one of these central repository or both.

Once uploaded and synced , you can simply reference your library using

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.your.groupid:artifactid:x.x.x'
}
```

and thats it.