# How can i make my Android project avaliable from remote by using gradle like Picasso,Volley etc.?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

Maybe lots of people will downvote this question, but I really have to ask someone. I searched for days for a good explanation but couldn't find any.

Here is my question:

I am not asking hot to add it as a module. When using Picasso, Volley, NineOldDroids etc., you add them as dependencies in gradle and then pull them from a remote source. How can I make my project avaliable from a remote source, as a gradle dependency?

So anyone can get my project through gradle.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would say that this question might not be in the scope of Stackoverflow. But anyway have you read [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)? It's not gradle that does the trick, you should read about Maven, then just configure Maven repository and that's it

Comment: Thank you Chaosit. I read lots of things about Maven but there is no full explanation from a simple HelloWorld application and putting it into Maven.I am not looking a huge thing.Just a tutorial on how to add a HelloWorld application into Maven and getting it by adding to gradle dependiency

Comment: how about [this guide](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073230/maven-repository-in-three-steps.html)? it explains the way to setup maven repository in simple way

Comment: Try bintray: http://blog.bintray.com/2014/02/11/bintray-as-pain-free-gateway-to-maven-central/

Comment: Check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31063503/2745762